# Axios POST request block by created() method

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm a beginner in development. I currently use Vue.JS and Axios to make API requests. On my application I have a created() method which retrieves a travel list via axios with a get() method. For each trip I make a list in a Navbar.

On the other side, I have a button that allows me to create a new trip via Axios and a post method.

The problem is that when I added my created() method, the functionality of adding a trip no longer worked, I got a 400 error message: "Request failed with status code 400".

Script:

```html
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  
  data(){
    return {
       'travel': {
         pays:"",
         capitale:"",
         date_debut: "",
         date_fin:"",
        //  drapeau:"",
      
       }
    };
  },
  methods:{
    saveTravel(){
      axios.post("api/travel", this.travel).then(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
          }
      )
    },

  },
  created(){
    axios.get("api/travels").then(
      response => this.travel = response.data
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried the async/await system in vue.js, but I don't have enough knowledge about it.

Comment: check `api/travels` request detail. maybe you do missing somethings in request or maybe an error in backend

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove single qoute from data object:

```
data() {
 retrun {
  travel: {
        pays:"",
        capitale:"",
        date_debut: "",
        date_fin:"",
      }
   };
 },
```

2. Try to transform your created() hook as:

```
async created() {
   try {
     const response = await axios.get("api/travels");
     if(response) {
     this.travel = response.data; // According to your response
     }
   } catch (error) {
     console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
   }
 },
```

3. please check your API, and send data to post method accordingly.
4. Use try/catch to catch proper error with async await.

```
async saveTravel() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("api/travel", this.travel);
    console.log("Response:", response);
    // resetting travel object
    this.travel = {
      pays: "",
      capitale: "",
      date_debut: "",
      date_fin: "",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested what you sent me. I still have the same error : "Request failed with status code 400"

Comment: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
saveTravel @ VM62 Sidebar-map.vue:42
await in saveTravel (asynchrone)  
onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ VM60 Sidebar-map.vue:179
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:158
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:278